Drop duplicates when querying multiple tables in Django
I have a custom manager with search, which orders return results by rank:
class MyManager(models.Manager):
    
    def search(self, query, fa, fb=None, fc=None, fd=None, qs=None):
        
        if not qs:
            qs = self.get_queryset()

        try:

            if not (1 in [c in query for c in '&|()!*:"']):
                query = " & ".join([f"{q}:*" for q in query.split()])

            vector = SearchVector(*fa, weight="A", config="english")
            if fb:
                vector += SearchVector(*fb, weight="B", config="english")
            if fc:
                vector += SearchVector(*fc, weight="C", config="english")
            if fd:
                vector += SearchVector(*fd, weight="D", config="english")
            query = SearchQuery(query, search_type="raw")
            qs = (
                qs.annotate(search=vector, rank=SearchRank(vector, query))
                .filter(search=query)
                .order_by("-rank", "-id")
                .distinct("rank", "id")
            )
            qs.count()  # Trigger exception

        except (ProgrammingError, UnboundLocalError):
            qs = qs.none()

        return qs

But when I try searching on related fields, it still returns duplicate results:
class Case(models.Model):
    machine = models.ForeignKey(Machine, on_delete=models.CASCADE)   
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)    
    hashtags = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    closed = models.BooleanField(default=False)  

    objects = MyManager()


class CaseProgress(models.Model):
    case = models.ForeignKey(Case, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    desc = models.TextField()


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class CaseListView(ListView):
    model = Case

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get("query", None)
        show_closed = (
            True if self.request.GET.get("show_closed", False) == "true" else False
        )
        if query:
            if not show_closed:
                qs = self.model.objects.filter(closed=False)
            else:
                qs = self.model.objects.all()
            fa = (
                "id",
                "machine__serial_number",
                "machine__company__name",
                "user__user__first_name",
                "user__user__last_name",
            )
            fb = ("hashtags",)
            fc = ("caseprogress__desc",)
            qs = self.model.objects.search(
                query, fa, fb, fc, qs=qs
            )
            return qs

Now I run a search and the query can be found in different tables, than in returns both results, even though i have id in distinct. Why is that? I've read Django's manual on this subject, but it doesn't seem to apply in my case, since I am not ordering on the ralated fields.

Your query specifies .distinct("rank", "id"), which is not identical to .distinct("id").
The former will get distinct results that match both of the fields, not one or the other. Which is to say that rows with the same id will still appear in the queryset so long as they don't have the same rank.
EDIT in response to comment:
The docs say this about distinct when you're using Postgres:

When you specify field names, you must provide an order_by() in the
QuerySet, and the fields in order_by() must start with the fields in
distinct(), in the same order.

In other words, any field listed in distinct must also be listed in order_by. BUT the reverse is not required - you can list fields in order_by without listing them in distinct (you can omit distinct entirely if you wanted and order_by would still work).
The docs list a specific example showcasing this:
# Examples (those after the first will only work on PostgreSQL):
Entry.objects.order_by("author", "pub_date").distinct("author")


I suspected the same. But if I need to order the queryset by rank and get disticnt ids, how do I get that?

You could try .order_by("rank").distinct(). For many use-cases, that should be enough.

That will return duplictes.
